# Custom error page does not render when an exception occurs in Create method of ApplicationUserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET Identity in my MVC project.
When I make a request for my login page, Configuration method of Startup class is called. In which, Create method of ApplicationUserManager class is called. In this method an exception occurs but custom error page does not render.

[image]

My Web.Config :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty obvious from the error message

> An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

1. So your login screen has an error.
2. ASP tries to execute your `~/Views/Shared/Error.html` and return its result.
3. Step 2 failed because there is some sort of error with executing `~/Views/Shared/Error.html`.
4. So ASP gives you the message you got - it cannot, afterall, go back and use `~/Views/Shared/Error.html` to report the error on `~/Views/Shared/Error.html`, can it.

I suggest you have a close look at `~/Views/Shared/Error.html` so see whether

a) it actually exists, and
b) if it exists, whether it contains any errors of its own.

either a) will be false or b) will be true.

Comment: Error page exists and also in other exceptional cases, it renders fine.
I am getting this issue only in this case.

Comment: Do you need to be logged in, in order for the error page to be shown to you? If so, and you get an error during login attempts, you'd have a situation where the page cannot be rendered from your current position.

Comment: No, I do not need to log in to display custom error page.
Can you try this scenario at your side?